# Оптимизация кода и триггер на коллизию

Tags: unity3d

Есть небольшой код, когда объект двигаешь по карте, в нужном месте где можно строить объект весь зеленый, где нельзя красный.

**Проблема:** когда создаю объект при помощи button в месте, где строить можно объект горит красным, но когда я объект толкаю в горы, а потом обратно в ровную местность то все нормально. 
Т.е. чтобы построить мне надо сделать, чтобы триггер сработал, как от этого избавиться? 
И еще в update идет постоянная проверка материала как это можно убрать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material matGhostGreen;
    public Material matGhostRed;
    public Material matNormal;



    string tagCreate = "CreateUnit";
    string tagComplete = "CompleteUnit";
    public bool sBefore = false;

    public BoxCollider bc1;
    public BoxCollider bc2;
    void Start()
    {
        GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("!!!!!!");
    if (gameObject.tag == tagCreate)
    {
        if ( GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit==false)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matGhostGreen;
        }
        if(GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit == true)
        {

            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matGhostRed;
        }

    }



      /*  if ((gameObject.tag == tagCreate) && (GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit == true))
        {


            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = GhostNone;



        }*/

        if (GlobalVar.activeCreateUnit == false)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matNormal;


            gameObject.tag = tagComplete;
            bc1.enabled = true;
            bc2.enabled = false;
            Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("dfgdgdfg");
       // if (other.attachedRigidbody)
       // {
        //    other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10);
        //}
    }
```

Вот что висит на объекте, там два box collider это когда после установки объекта, один удалится бокс колайдер а другой появляется но уже поменьше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот не могу ставить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это когда я пройдусь объектом по горе тогда можно ставить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно слово "Оптимизация" и "Коллизию"

Comment: @Allespro, в следующий раз предлагайте правку.